# Spring 3 Web MVC - @Controller method() pre & post processing functionality through annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'd like to be able to have the following:

```
@Controller    
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/someurl", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @PreProcess
    @PostProcess
    public String doStuff(ModelMap map) {
        //do stuff
        return "someurl";
    }

}
```

The `@PreProcess` and `@PostProcess` are arbitrarily named Annotations.

I've been looking for a working example of this but I can't find any. I've looked at AOP and the use of the `@Aspect` annotation but I found it quite complex. A working example of what I'm trying to do would be great.

I've sampled Spring Security in the past but this isn't quite what I need because I need the processing to be custom, pretty much anything I want.

I know that this functionality is available in .Net MVC. Hoping it's available in Spring also.

Any help or pointers really appreciated.

Comment: check `@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy` here http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-postconstruct-and-predestroy-example/

Comment: what exactly are you trying to trigger pre and post? will these annotations point to something that is going to execute, or will the method itself be executed pre and post something?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. Yes the pre and post annotations will point to something that will execute before and after the @Controller method() is called/finished. Not the latter as you described it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can annotate a method with [`@ModelAttribute`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ModelAttribute.html) to execute a method before a controller method. Or use an [`interceptor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor)

Example with `@ModelAttribute`

```
@Controller    
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/someurl", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String doStuff(@ModelAttribute("something") Something something, ModelMap map) {
        //do stuff
        // here you can do what you want with something it has been provided to you in the method parameters
        return "someurl";
    }

    @ModelAttribute("something")
    public Something something() {
        // do what you need
        return new Something();
    }
}
```

The `something()` method will be called before every method having a `@RequestMapping` annotation, thus before the `doStuff()` method.

Comment: thanks very much, that seems to do the trick. Am I correct in saying that the url's these interceptors are to be applied to are only configurable in the app-context XML? From what I can find, it seems that the interceptors can only be applied to certain URL's via XML and not Annotations?

Comment: You are right, it is only possible to configure interceptor via XML configuration. Maybe in next release they will make it possible via annotations. However, interceptors are not only available for specific url, you may use them globally. Just don't define any URL for it.

Comment: See for example the following `LocaleChangeInterceptor` that can be defined globally so that the locale can be changed to French on any URL by adding `?locale=fr`. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/i18n/LocaleChangeInterceptor.html

Comment: @Alex will something() method be called only for methods having a RequestMapping in the same class or globally?

Comment: @veritas It will be called by any method in the current `Controller` requesting a `@ModelAttribute` object in its param, so if in any other controller method you ask Spring to give you a Something it will look for a method annotated with `@ModelAttribute` in its current controller to call it.