# How to secure resources of a different user

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-security

Let's say we have an endpoint:
`/api/v1/users/{username}/profile` this endpoint is responsible for updating a user profile. The problem is that the current user may update a profile of a different user, so how can we prevent that? Current user should be able to update only his profile, the validation should not validate an administrator. There are many similar endpoints, so I am looking for a good way how to handle it.

Comment: either use HTTP sessions or pass an authentication token to the API.

Comment: I do use the JWT token authentication, so I have the Principal.

Comment: just check if `yourPrincipal.getName()` equals the `username` from the path?

Comment: See this section of our [SpringOne 2021](https://youtu.be/5tlU_Vjv8Ns?t=1731) presentation which shows how to protect an endpoint using advanced authorization scenarios like this with `@PreAuthorize` or `@PostAuthorize` annotations

Comment: @dan1st Yeah I thought about it, but how do it effectively without duplicating the code in each controller method.

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071191/spring-3-web-mvc-controller-method-pre-post-processing-functionality-thro and throwing an exception if the authentication doesn't work out?

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use spring security (check [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/))

You can add spring security to your project and then you can get user data by authorization header (or it may be a jwt token) and just change the endpoint to this

PUT /api/v1/users/profile

send the updated details with the body, and get userID from auth header and then you can apply the updation. using this method only current logged in users will be updated